# Use cross-validation trained models for out-of-sample prediction or train a new model using whole data?

Tags: time-series, svm, matlab, libsvm

I'm using `support vector regression(SVR)` model and 5-fold cross validation for price prediction. which one is more appropriate after training models for out-of-sample prediction (tomorrow unknown price)?

- Using 5 trained model and average between output of models for next day price prediction?
- Train a new SVR model by whole data using selected parameters (I'm using greed search in this and above procedure) and predict next day price using this new single trained model?

Answer (score 1):

Cross-validation is used for model selection i.e. comparing between candidate models and determing their parameters. Once you have made your model/pamaeter choice on the basis of minimising test error, you should use the entire dataset to train a new model for your actual predictions.

Comment: thank you for answer. Based on your procedure if we want predict next day after tomorrow (trend prediction) we should train our model in every step? For example after prediction next day price we add this price to our model and train it again or we use same trained model in first step?

Comment: I would say that how often you should update your model by performing the aforementioned procedure of model selection etc. depends on how much new data you have, how different they are to the existing data etc.

Comment: Consider mentioned procedure. I want predict next 7 days so in every step I have one new price (predicted price). We need model updating in every step in this case? I think the amount of new data is very low.

Comment: I cannot possibly give an answer to this question as it is largely application dependent. I suggest testing across different update frequency scenarios to determine the optimal trade-off between computational burden and improvement of prediction quality.